# R - Removing rows in data frame by list of column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two `data frames`, one containing the `predictors` and one containing the different `categories` I want to predict. Both of the data frames contain a column named `geoid`. Some of the rows of my predictors contains `NA` values, and I need to remove these. 
After extracting the `geoid` value of the rows containing `NA` values, and removing them from the `predictors` `data frame` I need to remove the corresponding rows from the `categories` `data frame` as well.
It seems like a rather basic operation but the code won't work.

```
categories <- as.data.frame(read.csv("files/cat_df.csv"))
predictors <- as.data.frame(read.csv("files/radius_100.csv"))
NA_rows <- predictors[!complete.cases(predictors),]
geoids <- NA_rows['geoid']
clean_categories <- categories[!(categories$geoid %in% geoids),]
```

None of the rows in `categories/clean_categories` are removed.

A typical geoid value is `US06140231`. `typeof(categories$geoid)` returns `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say this is it, but a very basic typo won't be doing what you want, try this correction

```
clean_categories <- categories[!(categories$geoid %in% geoids),]
```

Almost certainly this is what you meant to happen in that line. You want to negate the result of the %in% operator. You don't include a reproducible example so I can't say whether the whole thing will do as you want.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. It still won't remove the rows though. Do you have any other idea how I can remove the rows without hardcoding them?

Comment: Why don't you join the data frames first and then do a single filter?
Also, read.csv() returns a data.frame so no need to wrap with as.data.frame().